# Cant figure out why im getting IndexError: string index out of range python

Tags: python, index-error

so Im working on a codesignal problem, and these are the instructions:

```
Given a string, your task is to replace each of its characters by the next one in the English alphabet; i.e. replace a with b, replace b with c, etc (z would be replaced by a).

Example

For inputString = "crazy", the output should be alphabeticShift(inputString) = "dsbaz".

Input/Output

[execution time limit] 4 seconds (py3)

[input] string inputString

A non-empty string consisting of lowercase English characters.

Guaranteed constraints:
1 ≤ inputString.length ≤ 1000.

[output] string

The resulting string after replacing each of its characters.
```

this is my code:

```
def alphabeticShift(inputString):
    abc = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyza"
    newString = ""
    for letter in inputString:
        abcIndex = 0
        for abcletter in abc:
          
          if letter == abcletter:
              newString = newString+abc[abcIndex+1]
          abcIndex = abcIndex+1
    return newString

print(alphabeticShift("*_fArgs_uiutgbodsupy"))
```

I have tried my code in replit and it executes just fine but I keep getting this error when I put it in codesignal:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File main.py3 in the pre-written template, in getUserOutputs
    userOutput = _rundngpj(testInputs[i])

  File main.py3 in the pre-written template, in _rundngpj
    return alphabeticShift(*_fArgs_asixuqfdhzqc)

  File main.py3 on line 10, in alphabeticShift
    newString = newString+abc[abcIndex+1]
IndexError: string index out of range
```

I dont know what I am missing as i dont see how anything could be out of range?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add a break statement inside the if condition.

```py
if letter == abcletter:
    newString = newString+abc[abcIndex+1]
    break
```

The reason it fails is when you encounter `a`, you are trying to replace it twice, once at the start and once in the end of `abc` which fails.

Answer (score 1):

You don't exit your `for abcLetter` loop after having found a letter, and `a` is there twice. So when `letter` is `"a"`, you add `"b"`, then you *continue* to loop, find the other `"a"` and try to add the letter after it as well — but there is none. A `break` after you append the letter will fix it.

That said, there is much here that is non-idiomatic, the solution can be much simpler — e.g. by using `str.translate`:

```
shift = str.maketrans(
  'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz',
  'bcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyza',
)
def alphabeticShift(inputString):
    return inputString.translate(shift)
```